# How to confirm if the backups are going to tape in SQL Server 2005 and 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, backup

We have many of our SQL Servers where we take the backup locally on the server as well as over the network to other server in case of disaster.

Also, we have a process set that server support team takes those backups on drives for a defined time out to tapes.

Recently we had an issue where server went down and didn't had the backups on its alternative server and so needed to recover them from tape. Initially even from tape that could not be located, something was a miss for sure but we got it finally.

So instead of being dependent on other team, is there a way in SQL may be via script we can get a report or build something that confirms backups are going successfully onto the tape and when?

Please advise, if it can be achieved. Thanks!

Comment: You have to check the ARCHIVE `a` bit on the file attributes. You can easily do it using powershell.

Comment: The only way to be certain you can recover from backup is with a `RESTORE`.  It's a good practice to test your recovery plan periodically against a test instance.  The details depend on your tape backup solution.  Ideally, the restore process can be scripted so that it is repeatable and reliable.

Comment: You can check backup history tables there would be an entry and if you run `Exec sp_readerrorlog 0,1,'VIRTUAL_DEVICE'` and it returns some information. Read thoes information whenever backup happens on tape drive backup message is dumped in error log with location as virtual device.

Comment: @Shanky if you are using third party backup software like `redgate's sql backup pro` then it will use `VIRTUAL_DEVICE` --> `VIRTUAL_DEVICE: {'SQLBACKUP_guid}`. Also, scanning error log on a busy PROD system will be an additional load.

Comment: @Kin Ya correct but VIRTUAL_DEVICE keyword would be there all I wanted to say is if backup happens successfully using TP tool virtual device keyword is also a way to find it. Depending on size of errorlog it might have to scan some big chunk, in that case seeing backup history is better option. But frankly speaking I am not sure about load it will cause if it has to scan.

Comment: Thanks @Shanky, By running Exec sp_readerrorlog 0,1,'VIRTUAL_DEVICE i am able to see the full and other backups showing going to virtual device dumping the file from the location of backup source, but i believe it does not let us know where exactly it goes. Reading the log is perfect for my small servers but for my heavy servers with lots of databases, it is taking almost 10 minutes to display the information :(

Comment: Thanks @Kin, I can see that attribute a . But how to do it via Powershell is a huge ask, as i am not that much into Powershell. Also, i believe attribute a is flagged for a file with latest archive like today only, for previous it seem to be unflagged, means cannot see the attribute a among the files.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure that you're backups are going to tape, you need to periodically recall the tapes and restore the backups. We recall tapes once every three months to do this, it seems like a lot of effort but it is not overkill if you value having offsite backups.